# Cant use Micro-Coap library for arduino

Tags: sockets, arduino, coap

I am trying to get the micro-coap librarby (https://github.com/1248/microcoap)
to work on my arduino. When I try to compile it in the Arduino IDE, it reports that `<sys/socket.h>` dependency in `main-posix.c` can not be found.

Searches for the problem were not helpful, except for some general C++ answer that was hinting that there is no `sys/socket.h` on Windows. But this should not have anything to do with Arduino right?

I looked at the ethernet library for arduino and there is a `socket.h` but it is not in a sys directory.

Hope you can help

Comment: may I ask you which Arduino are you using with micro-coap library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone suggested simply taking the file out of the arduino path / deleting it and that worked. As Stefan posted in his answer, it is used to build the library on unix/linux and has no relevance for arduino.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `main-posix.c` source file is meant to be compile for a UNIX/LINUX based operating system. If you want to use Windows to compile `main-posix.c`, you can use projects like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Arduino does not have `<sys/socket.h>` dependency needed to compile `main-posix.c`. Instead open `microcoap.ino` in the Arduino IDE and compile and flash it to the hardware.

Comment: The problem was that compiling the sketch did not work. Someone suggested simply taking the file out of the arduino path / deleting it and that worked.