# Unable to use microcoap library due to this error. Any fixes?

Tags: c++, c, unix, arduino, coap

I am unable to use `microcoap` library (https://github.com/1248/microcoap) in Arduino IDE. When I try to compile it produces following error

```
main-posix.c:1:24: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
#include <sys/socket.h>
                      ^
```

This question has already been answered in ([Cant use Micro-Coap library for arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222912/cant-use-micro-coap-library-for-arduino)) but the answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try to find the path where `socket.h` is, if it isn't there? Or make sure the compiler knows the path, since `sys/socket.h` isn't a full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete that main-posix.c because this is necessary for linux, not Arduino. It will definitely work.